# Getting Sheet Name From Excel

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I am uploading excel files to a SQL Server database. I am currently using this line to get the data from the sheet:

```
string myQuery = "Select * from [Sheet1$]";
```

The problem is, if the sheet name isn't `Sheet1` then it will fail. Is there a way to get the sheet name rather than hard coding in `Sheet1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the schema first using [`GetOleDbSchemaTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.getoledbschematable.aspx):

```
DataTable schemaTable = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(
    OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables,
    new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
```

The name of the first table should be at `schemaTable.Rows[0][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Function GetSheetNames(ByVal ExcelFile As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim _Sheets As Sheets = Nothing
    Dim LstSheetName As List(Of String) = Nothing
    Try
        LstSheetName = New List(Of String)
        Using Document As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(ExcelFile, False)
            Dim _WorkbookPart As WorkbookPart = Document.WorkbookPart
            _Sheets = _WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets
        End Using

        For Each Item As Sheet In _Sheets
            LstSheetName.Add(Item.Name)
        Next
        Return LstSheetName
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Function
```